# Accuracy of comparison of runtime

Tags: r, performance, replicate

All, I am wondering whether the following will give me an accurate assesment of the runtimes of these functions. I would be confident of the result if I knew whether the replications were done sequentially, but I don't. Thanks.

```
system.time(replicate(8000,function1(4,5)))
system.time(replicate(8000,function2(4,5)))
system.time(replicate(8000,function3(4,5)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code of `replicate` you will see that is this:

```
> replicate
function (n, expr, simplify = "array") 
sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
    simplify = simplify)
<bytecode: 0x000000000b3b1ee8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Since it uses `sapply` in its source code then yes it is sequential as `sapply` is actually a `for-loop` written in `C`. So, yes it is quite an accurate assessment in this respect.

You could also try the `microbenchmark` package which would calculate even more precisely the running times.